# Checking if a user have a certain role in an array of role

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make a command that is only available for certain roles only.
I tried checking them in an array, but it doesn't seem to work.

the command:

```
const Command = require("../structures/Command.js");
const config = require("../data/config.json");

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "test",
    description: "test",

    async run(message, args, client) {
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.id === config.adminRoles)) {return message.reply("You have the admin role")} else {message.reply("No")}
    }
});
```

config.json

```
{
"token": "token_go_here",
"prefix": "ab!",
"adminRoles": ["931469781234769940","931462231969910794"],
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `roles.cache.some()` as listed on the Collection docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection

```js
if (roles.cache.some(role => config.adminRoles.includes(role.id))) {
 // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do this:

config.json

```json
{
"token": "token_go_here",
"prefix": "ab!",
"admin1": "931469781234769940",
"admin2": "931462231969910794"
}
```

command.js

```js
const Command = require("../structures/Command.js");
const { admin1, admin2 } = require("../data/config.json")

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "test",
    description: "test",

    async run(message, args, client) {
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        if (message.member.roles.cache.has(admin1) || message.member.roles.cache.has(admin2)) {
            return message.reply("You have the admin role")
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what if I want to check more than 3 IDs?
Do I need to `|| message.member.roles.cache.has(adminN)` everytime?

Comment: No if you are doing more than 2 it's better to do a collection cause otherwise your if statement will get really long with all of the "or" (aka `||`) clauses thrown in.